# What's the syntax of following c++ code?

Tags: c++

In following c++ code, what is the purpose of the `LinkedList<Derived>::`? I never see that syntax.

```
template<class Derived, class List> LinkedListItem<Derived, List>::~LinkedListItem() {
    if(_list) _list->LinkedList<Derived>::cut(static_cast<Derived*>(this));
}
```

I try to search before asking, but just can not find anything. Sorry if there is already a post on that.

Comment: Which highlighted code, the light blue or dark blue?

Comment: Looks like it's calling a base class function.

Comment: It's explicitly calling the member `cut` belonging to `LinkedList<Derived>`.

Comment: Exactly my question, why need such "qualifier"? "cut" belong to _list which type is a template type when defines LinkedListItem.

Comment: Here is linklist and LinkedListItem definition,

template<class Derived, class List>
class LinkedListItem { 
    friend class LinkedList<Derived>;     
    ...
    List *_list;
}

template<class T> class LinkedList {
    public:
      void cut(T* item)
}
 
Why need to add qualifier to call cut from list?

Comment: Possibly to constrain `List` to be `LinkedList<Derived>` or a derived class, and also ensure that even if it's a derived class, it still calls the base class method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you have two classes:

```
struct A
{
   virtual void foo() {std::cout << "Came to A::foo()\n";}
};

struct B : A
{
   virtual void foo() {std::cout << "Came to B::foo()\n";}
};
```

and a pointer:

```
A* ap = new B();
```

If you call

```
ap->foo();
```

You will execute `B::foo()`. However, if you want to execute `A::foo()` on that pointer, you can use:

```
ap->A::foo();
```

Coming to your posted code,

If you add some white space and put things in multiple lines, the same code is:

```
template<class Derived, class List>
LinkedListItem<Derived, List>::~LinkedListItem()
{
    if(_list) 
        _list->LinkedList<Derived>::cut(static_cast<Derived*>(this));
}
```

The line

```
template<class Derived, class List>
```

indicates that we are looking at a class template, a class template member function, or a function template.

The line

```
LinkedListItem<Derived, List>::~LinkedListItem()
```

indicates that we are looking at the destructor of the class template `LinkedListItem`.

The lines

```
    if(_list) 
        _list->LinkedList<Derived>::cut(static_cast<Derived*>(this));
```

indicate that `LinkedListItem` has a member variable `_list`. If the member variable `_list` is not NULL, we are invoking some function on it.

The line

```
        _list->LinkedList<Derived>::cut(static_cast<Derived*>(this));
```

seems to indicate that the type of `_list` has a base class template called `LinkedList` that has a member function called `cut`. The line calls that function using an argument that is obtained by casting `this` to a `Derived*`.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList<Derived>` is a type and it is also a `scope`. `::` is the scope operator which tells the compiler that the scope of `cut(static_cast<Derived*>(this))` it resides (LinkedList).

Answer (score 0):

The following is a likely structure : `LinkedList<Derived>` is a template class implemented a linked list of `Derived` objects. It is composed to `LinkedListItem<Derived, List>` objects which wrap around a `Derived*` and maintain the other data components relevant to a linked list(next, prev pointers, head pointer, etc). Every `LinkedListItem<Derived,List>` object also contains a pointer to the `LinkedList<Derived>` object it is part of. This is `_list`. So, when you destroy a `LinkedListItem`, you also want to `cut` it from the original list. `cut` will likely modify the contents of the neighbours of the `LinkedListItem` being deleted in order to maintain all the `LinkedList` invariants.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedList<Derived>` in `_list->LinkedList<Derived>::cut(static_cast<Derived*>(this));` means that the function `cut` belongs to `LinkedList<Derived>` template, as you can notice by the scope operator `::`